# Add Persistant column with different Collate

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, galera

I have a MariaDB Galera cluster with 3 nodes

The database is created with latin1_swedish_ci and i want to add a new column with this command

`ALTER TABLE pakkeshop.leveringer ADD reverse_stregkode VARCHAR(45) COLLATE latin1_danish_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REVERSE(Stregkode)) PERSISTENT;`

That gives me an error and i need the coloumn to be in latin1_danish_ci

```
ALTER TABLE pakkeshop.leveringer MODIFY reverse_stregkode VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_danish_ci;
```

If i try to execute the command above the node crashes and has to be rebooted.
(The node has been taken out of the cluster before i run these commands)

Comment: Please file a bug at https://jira.mariadb.org , including `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before the crashing statement, MariaDB version that you are using, stack trace (crash report from server error log), and your cnf file(s).

Answer (score 0):

I was running MariaDB V10.1.18 and upgrading to V10.1.22 solved the problem